# PhoneGap - Cordova / Application freeze during 5 seconds when resumed through app icon

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I own an AngularJs app that I converted into a native app through Cordova.

The whole works on iOS (iphone), however I've just noticed that if I put the app on the background, then reopen/resume it, the application sometimes "freezes" for about 5 seconds then works. 
No scrolling, no click events, for 5 seconds.

Any known reason to this? How to avoid it? It's very frustrating.

I found the code causing the issue:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('retrieveAllNotifications', null);
            }, false);
```

So, according to the documentation:

> Interactive functions like alert() when the resume event fires will
>   need to be wrapped in a setTimeout call with a timeout value of zero,
>   or else the app will hang. e.g.

So I transformed to:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('retrieveAllNotifications', null);
                }, 0);
            }, false);
```

but it still hangs.

However, when I remove the broadcast, it works.

How to fix it? Increasing the timeout to 1 second for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I noticed that I retrieved more than 500 notifications that are displayed (though hidden) in HTML.

What I've done is to delete a lot of notifications, and I noticed no more freeze.

It was just too heavy for the phonegap app to display 500 notifications at once without freezing.